# Taskkill no longer works with VLC

Tags: batch-file, vlc, taskkill

I have a batch that used to kill VLC.

```
echo
rem choice /c YN /n /d Y /t 120
taskkill /im vlc.exe
```

Now when it runs, VLC stays open, even though the CMD reports the taskkill command was successfully sent.

Any ideas? Perhaps a VLC (currently 2.1.5) update make it no longer work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `taskkill /im vlc.exe /f` or `taskkill /im vlc.exe /t /f` working for you? Had the same problem with explorer.exe a while ago...

Comment: `taskkill /im vlc.exe /f` worked thank you. Also, I simplified the example above. I have other lines with taskkill that still worked on those apps. Would you recommend adding the `/f` flag to them too?

Comment: Using the /f switch forces the program to terminate abruptly, so you'll lose any unsaved data. (This applies to local applications only, task-killing a remote program will force its termination, even without the /f switch. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx for more information)

Comment: OK thanks for the tip. I'll just use `/f` on VLC as the others are working as is and may suffer from data loss.